# How to create new table where database's name begin with ...?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know if there is a solution to create a new table in many databases depends on their name.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here is my script for create new table :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[E_Invent2](
    [D_No] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Mo_Droits] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Pr_Code] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Pr_Libellé] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [In_Stk08] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk09] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk10] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk11] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk12] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk01] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk02] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk03] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk04] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk05] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk06] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk07] [real] NULL,
    [In_StkMoy] [real] NULL,
    [In_StkReel] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtConstElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_TauxElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_DeducAutoElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtTaxElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtConstEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_VolEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_TauxEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_DeducAutoEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtTaxEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtTaxTotal] [real] NULL,
    [In_ManquantTaxable] [real] NULL,
    [In_TotalDroits] [real] NULL,
    [D_Nom] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [D_Enseigne] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [D_Adr1] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [D_Adr2] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [D_Post] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [D_Adr3] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_E_Invent2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [D_No] ASC,
    [Mo_Droits] ASC,
    [Pr_Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would like to execute it for all databases where database's name begin with CM_0.

I found a solution to drop table :

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql=''
select @sql=@sql+' drop table '+table_name from INFORMATION_SCEHMA.TABLES where table_name like 'tmp_%'
exec(@sql)
```

But 'drop' command line is simpler than 'create' command line...

Is anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance

Cooxkie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better and cheaper way to do this. This is very very simple and works perfectly.

With `SELECT INTO` statement you can copy the structure of a table as well as data to another table in same or external databases.
Reference:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)
SET @sql=''
SELECT @sql=@sql+'; SELECT * INTO '+name+'.dbo.E_Invent2 FROM OriginalDB.dbo.E_Invent2' FROM sysdatabases WHERE name LIKE 'CM_0%' and name<>'OriginalDB'
SELECT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Here `OrigialDB` is the name of database where you have this table.

If your table in `OrginalDB` carries data and you don't want to copy data and need to copy only the structure then you may try this-

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)   

SET @sql=''
    SELECT @sql=@sql+'; SELECT * INTO '+name+'.dbo.E_Invent2 FROM OriginalDB.dbo.E_Invent2 WHERE 1<>1' FROM sysdatabases WHERE name LIKE 'CM_0%' and name<>'OriginalDB'
    SELECT @sql
    EXEC(@sql)
```

This should work else let me know if I can help you.

NOTE: Constraints will not be copied

Comment: The method you share me is only for select statement, not for create table statement, isn't it ?

Comment: No, it's not just a `select` statement rather it's `SELECT INTO` statement which copies data from one table to another table (external database) along with the table structure.

Comment: You are a genious ;-) ! It's very tricky and so good. Thanks you very much!

Comment: NB : I needed to add [] around my database because of "-" in database's name.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = ''
Declare @tablename nvarchar(max) = 'MyTab'
Declare @PreSyntax nvarchar(max) = 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE ' 

Declare @PostSyntax nvarchar(max) = '(
    [D_No] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Mo_Droits] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Pr_Code] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Pr_Libellé] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [In_Stk08] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk09] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk10] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk11] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk12] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk01] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk02] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk03] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk04] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk05] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk06] [real] NULL,
    [In_Stk07] [real] NULL,
    [In_StkMoy] [real] NULL,
    [In_StkReel] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtConstElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_TauxElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_DeducAutoElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtTaxElab] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtConstEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_VolEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_TauxEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_DeducAutoEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtTaxEmbout] [real] NULL,
    [In_PrtTaxTotal] [real] NULL,
    [In_ManquantTaxable] [real] NULL,
    [In_TotalDroits] [real] NULL,
    [D_Nom] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [D_Enseigne] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [D_Adr1] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [D_Adr2] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [D_Post] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [D_Adr3] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_E_Invent2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [D_No] ASC,
    [Mo_Droits] ASC,
    [Pr_Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]'

Select @Sql = @Sql + char(10) + @PreSyntax + isnull(name,'') + '.dbo.' + @tablename + @PostSyntax + char(10)
from sys.sysdatabases d
where d.name like '%pattern%'

Select @Sql
```

Comment: Thanks you, it also works but Suvendu Shekhar Giri's method is very simpler, you should have a look on it, it's very tricky ;-)

Comment: Suvendu's solution will only work in case the table already exists in one of the databases. If you want to create a new table in multiple databases you have to provide the schema.

Comment: You're absolutely right. In my case I already get script for the first database. I ran it. And after I copied it to my 450 other databases. I was very impressed by the fast. Other drawback : SELECT INTO doesn't copy the constraints, keys, or computed columns. It also does not copy over the indexes. But in my case I wasn't concerned :)